# Perl podusage generates man page with extra control-O's

Tags: terminal, perl, man

I am using `pod2usage` in a Perl script to generate a man page. The code looks like this:

```
use Pod::Usage;
pod2usage(-verbose => 2) ;
exit 0 ;
... some code ...
__END__                                                                                                                             

=head1 NAME                                                                                                                         

my-program - program to do things                                                                   

=head1 SYNOPSIS                                                                                                                     

B<my-program> ( help | status | version )                                                                              

B<my-program> ( lock I<reason> )                                                                                                

B<my-program> ( unlock [I<username | ALL>] )
```

When I run the program I get the man page but it looks like this:

```
NAME^O
    my-program - program to do things

SYNOPSIS^O
    my-program^O ( facter | help | status | version )

    my-program^O ( lock reason^O )

    my-program^O ( unlock [username | ALL^O] )
```

In the above, the words are bold-faced and underlined but have these `^O`'s following them. Why are they there?

Note that if I do a simple man page (e.g., `man man`) the words that are bold-faced or underlined do not have `^O` suffixed.

This is happening on a Debian stretch machine in a bash shell with the `term` variable set to `linux`.

Comment: `^O` is ASCII `SI` (shift-in), which is used by quite a few terminals to signal a change in character attributes. So the first guess is a mismatch between terminal settings and whatever terminal emulator you are using. Also note that the `TERM` variable needs uppercase.

Answer (score 1):

I can (surprisingly) reproduce your issue on OpenBSD with `TERM` set to `linux` (or `rxvt`).  With `TERM` set to `vt100`, `screen`, `tmux`, `xterm` or other common terminals, I have no issue and the `^O` characters do not show up.

The only relevant information that I've been able to find relating to terminal capabilities is that `Pod::Text`, which `Pod::Usage` uses, *used* to use `termcap` sequences before it was rewritten. With `TERM=linux`, it doesn't seem to make any difference if `Pod::Usage` is using the default `Pod::Text` for formatting, or if it's made to use the `Pod::Text::Termcap` as explained in the `Pod::Usage` documentation:

> The default text formatter is `Pod::Text`. The base class for `Pod::Usage` can
>       be defined by pre-setting `$Pod::Usage::Formatter` *before* loading
>       `Pod::Usage`, e.g.:
>
> ```
> BEGIN { $Pod::Usage::Formatter = 'Pod::Text::Termcap'; }
> use Pod::Usage qw(pod2usage);
> ```

Make sure that your `TERM` variable is correctly set for the terminal that you are using.  Most terminas work well with either `xterm` or `xterm-color`, although sessions running in `screen` or `tmux` should have `TERM=screen` (both programs enforces this by default).

Comment: Although I did not say in my original post, I am not using X-windows or `xterm`. I do all my work from the command line by connecting to the server using ssh from a Windows client.

Comment: @rlandster Same here. I'm using `tmux` with `TERM=screen` over an SSH connection from a Windows laptop.

Comment: I usually have `term=linux`. Changing `term` to `vt100` makes the `^O`'s turn into `2`'s (a little better, but not much). Changing `term` to `xterm` the  `^O`'s go away altogether. Going back to `linux` and the `^O`'s return.